# Drill into other dimension or Hierarchy than used in original MDX

Tags: mdx, iccube-reporting

Using iccube reporting V6, I cannot find a way to drill thru another dimension / Hierarchy using Drilldown Strategy "mdxExpression".

When selecting this option, the "mdxExpression" field below is defaulted to `$member.children`

Can someone provide a working example of this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard MDX function?

```
Member_Expression.Children
```

The documentation on MSDN is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146018(v=sql.110).aspx

So for example to get the states (children) of the member United States it would be this:

```
SELECT 
  [Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[United States].Children ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: My question is more about how should be the syntax to replace the `$member.children` because when i use directly [Geography].`[Geography].[Country].&[United States].Children` it does not work.

Comment: in icCube is this a parameter? `$member`

Comment: Yes, it is a parameter, but then, maybe formatted differently... I cannot see that.